# How to transform block variant to default version?

Tags: block-editor

I have a simple block variation:

```
  wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
    'core/heading',
    {
      name: 'headline',
      title: __('Big title'),
      attributes: {
        className: 'headline'
      },
    },
  );
```

And I want to be able to transform from this variant to standard `core/heading` and back. How to achieve this? Tried to get it from [Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-transforms/), but with no success.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This seems like it would be better implemented as a block _style_: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/ Then you’d be able to just set the style to default.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't answer my question. The problem is simplified (and I can think about many other usages) with block styles is that you have only one CSS class applied - with variants you can set it up way more, besides - only one Style can be applied at the time.

Comment: That’s why it didn’t post it as an answer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carolina Nymark pointed out, that there is possibility to filter transforms as any other settings, so one can modify the transformation like this:

```
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { assign, merge } = lodash;
const { createBlock } = wp.blocks;

function transformHeading(settings, name) {

    // Filter only heading.
    if (name !== 'core/heading') {
        return settings;
    }

    return assign({}, settings, {
        transforms: merge(settings.transforms, {
            from: [
                {
                    type: 'block',
                    blocks: ['core/paragraph'],
                    transform: ({ content }) => {
                        return createBlock('core/heading', {
                            content,
                            className: 'headline',
                        });
                    },
                }
            ],
        }),
    });
}

addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'my-filters/transforms',
    transformHeading,
);
```

But there are still a few things that you can't modify:

- Name of the transformation (it's still named by the default block, not the variation)
- If the transformation for the "to" block is already in among the transforms, you'll replace it (you can't have two transforms to the same block)
- as of WP 5.9.2 it doesn't support transform within the same block - doesn't migrate the content (not sure why)